# where to save the unicorn PIDS and sockets path as the folders gets dissappers after mina deploy rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn, apache-mina

I have set up a server for deploying my rails app. I am not able to start unicorn service. It is giving me a failed status. I am totally new to this. So as per this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-rails-app-with-unicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04. I created the shared folders for the socket, PIDs on the server. but I am using mina for deployment after every release my shared folder which I manually created, disappears and goes away with the old release with my unicorn files. So I created that shared folders on my local Desktop but they are not getting pushed to the server via git. So where and how should I place my unicorn pids and sockets to make it working below are my files

my unicorn.rb file

```
root = "/home/deployer/apps/rails_app/current"
working_directory root
pid "#{root}/shared/unicorn.pid"
stderr_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"
stdout_path "#{root}/log/unicorn.log"

listen "/shared/unicorn.railsapp.sock"
worker_processes 2
timeout 30

preload_app true
```

My /etc/init.d/unicorn_rails_app file

```
set -e

    USAGE="Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|rotate|force-stop>"

    # app settings
    USER="ggg"
    APP_NAME="rails_app"
    APP_ROOT="/home/$USER/$APP_NAME/current"
    ENV="production"

    # environment settings
    PATH="/home/$USER/.rbenv/shims:/home/$USER/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
    CMD="cd $APP_ROOT && bundle exec unicorn -c config/unicorn.rb -E $ENV -D"
    PID="$APP_ROOT/shared/pids/unicorn.pid"
    OLD_PID="$PID.oldbin"

    # make sure the app exists
    cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1

    sig () {
      test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
    }

    oldsig () {
      test -s $OLD_PID && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_PID`
    }

    case $1 in
      start)
      sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
        echo "Starting $APP_NAME"
        su - $USER -c "$CMD"
        ;;
      stop)
        echo "Stopping $APP_NAME"
        sig QUIT && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Not running"
        ;;
      force-stop)
        echo "Force stopping $APP_NAME"
        sig TERM && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Not running"
        ;;
      restart|reload|upgrade)
        sig USR2 && echo "reloaded $APP_NAME" && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
        $CMD
        ;;
      rotate)
        sig USR1 && echo rotated logs OK && exit 0
        echo >&2 "Couldn't rotate logs" && exit 1
        ;;
      *)
        echo >&2 $USAGE
        exit 1
        ;;
    esac
```

my mina deploy.rb file

require 'mina/bundler'
    require 'mina/rails'
    require 'mina/git'
    require 'mina/rbenv'  # for rbenv support. (http://rbenv.org)

```
set :domain, 'mydomain'
set :term_mode, :nil
set :deploy_to, 'path'
set :repository, 'myrepo'
set :branch, 'master'
set :user, 'gg'    # Username in the server to SSH to.
set :keep_releases, 5


set :shared_paths, ['config/database.yml', 'config/secrets.yml', 'log','tmp']

task :environment do
  invoke :'rbenv:load'
end

task :setup => :environment do
  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/log"]

  queue! %[mkdir -p "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]
  queue! %[chmod g+rx,u+rwx "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config"]

  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/database.yml"]
  queue! %[touch "#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/secrets.yml"]
  queue  %[echo "-----> Be sure to edit '#{deploy_to}/#{shared_path}/config/database.yml' and 'secrets.yml'."]
  if repository
    repo_host = repository.split(%r{@|://}).last.split(%r{:|\/}).first
    repo_port = /:([0-9]+)/.match(repository) && /:([0-9]+)/.match(repository)[1] || '22'

    queue %[
      if ! ssh-keygen -H  -F #{repo_host} &>/dev/null; then
        ssh-keyscan -t rsa -p #{repo_port} -H #{repo_host} >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      fi
    ]
  end
end

desc "Deploys the current version to the server."
task :deploy => :environment do
  to :before_hook do
  end
  deploy do
    invoke :'git:clone'
    invoke :'deploy:link_shared_paths'
    invoke :'bundle:install'
    invoke :'rails:db_migrate'
    invoke :'rails:assets_precompile'
    invoke :'deploy:cleanup'

    to :launch do
      queue "mkdir -p #{deploy_to}/current/tmp2/"
      queue "touch #{deploy_to}/current/tmp2/restart.txt"
    end
  end
end
```

I am getting this errors

unicorn_rails_app.service - LSB: starts the unicorn app server
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/unicorn_rails_app; generated)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2019-06-04 07:35:52 
   UTC; 10s ago
      Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
   Process: 30422 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/unicorn_rails_app start 
  (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Answer (score 0):

Keep them in shared folder, you can create symlink to tmp folder in shared.

Comment: can you please show me how to create symlinks . if I manually create shared folder  like this on server it wont work